# CSS only works temporarily upon changing its value

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a placeholder whose content (table and buttons) is generated dynamically based on the user choice. And I wanted to make the table vertically scrollable, and while doing so I have faced this unusual CSS behavior for me:

So I have the place holder as follow:

```
<div id="srollableTableDiv">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "roundingProblems_ph" runat="server" />
</div>
```

and I am applying the following CSS on the div:

```
#srollableTableDiv { height:500px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid red; }
```

Now what happens is that when the table is generated, the CSS seems not to be working at all, but when I change a value in the CSS (for example make the border color to red or blue) the whole CSS would work in the browser without refreshing the page (I am using VS and chrome).. but once I refresh the page the CSS stops working again until I change CSS to another value!

Note: I am using bootstrap.

Could anyone explain what is the issue here? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "The whole CSS would work in the browser without refreshing the page"? Do you mean you tried to change from browser(F12 inspect element) or in the CSS file?

Comment: can you check if the css code is available in the page source ?

Comment: @Jayaraj.K I am using VS 2013, and when I modify CSS values it takes immediate effect in the browser (without refreshing) but if I refresh the CSS would stop working!.

Comment: Is the  css source refered in the page is the exactly the same as what you have in your root?

Comment: Yes it was, I think it has to do with the browser's cash. Now after I left it for few hours to work on other pages, it seems to be working fine.